# Change component's props onClick

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to achieve something but don't know how to get it working. here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import CheckBox from "./CheckBox";

class MainContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    this.onSelect= this.onSelect.bind(this);
    };
    onSelect(selected) {
     //change props only for the clicked checkbox and update state
    }
    render(){
     return (<div> 
               <CheckBox 
                label="Label"
                count="60"
                stateGroup="department"
                ticked={false}
                onClick = {this.onSelect}
              />
               <CheckBox 
                label="Label"
                count="60"
                stateGroup="language"
                ticked={false}
                onClick = {this.onSelect}
              />
            </div>)
  }

}
```

So, I have container "MainContainer" with "CheckBox" components inside and I want to keep my state in one place the "MainContainer" state. what I'm trying to do is onSelect I'd update the state as well as change the props for only the selected component but I don't know how to access that component inside the onSelect function. and I don't if I can directly change the props for a component in the first place.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all `props` can't be changed or updated, that's where `states` come in play, for you to be able to update your UI at will, you use state if I'm not wrong.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I thought so as well. just wanted to make sure I got that right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your descrition it seems that you want to be able to select without having to store the mapping of each checkbox in state. What you could do is if you want to be able to select multiple checkboxes, keep an array of selected items in the state array.

```
class MainContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedValues: []};
    this.onSelect= this.onSelect.bind(this);
    };
    onSelect(selected, checked) {
     //change props only for the clicked checkbox and update state
     if(checked) {
         //if the checkbox is check append id to the selected state array
         this.setState((prevState) => ({
              selectedValues: prevState.selectedValues.concat(selected);
         }))
     } else {
         //remove the value from state is its unchecked
         let selectedValues = [...this.state.selectedValues];
         const index = selectedValues.indexOf(selected);
         if(index > -1) {
             selectedValues = [...selectedValues.slice(0, index), ...selectedValues.slice(index + 1)];
         }
         this.setState({selectedValues});
     }
    }
    render(){
     return (<div> 
               <CheckBox 
                label="Label"
                count="60"
                stateGroup="department"
                ticked={this.state.selectedValues.indexOf("department") > -1}
                onClick = {this.onSelect}
              />
               <CheckBox 
                label="Label"
                count="60"
                stateGroup="language"
                ticked={this.state.selectedValues.indexOf("language") > -1}
                onClick = {this.onSelect}
              />
            </div>)
  }

}
```

and then you can call the onSelect function from child like

```
this.props.onClick(this.props.stateGroup, checkedState);
```

If in case you only want one `Checkbox` to be selected at a time, you should rather make use of `Radio` instead. However your task is even more simple in that case as you just need to store the `selectedValue` as a string instead of array

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set an initial state and then change that state on button click.

```
import React from "react";
import CheckBox from "./CheckBox";

class MainContainer extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     checked: false,
   };
   this.onSelect= this.onSelect.bind(this);
 };

 onSelect(selected) {
   this.setState({checked: selected}) // or maybe: selected.target.value
 }

 render(){
    return (
       <div> 
           <CheckBox 
            label="Label"
            count="60"
            stateGroup="department"
            ticked={false}
            onClick = {this.onSelect}
          />
           <CheckBox 
            label="Label"
            count="60"
            stateGroup="language"
            ticked={false}
            onClick = {this.onSelect}
          />
      </div>)
 }

}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. My problem is that I'm going to have like 15 CheckBox. as I understand from your reply I need to map each CheckBox to a property in the state to able control each one individually. even then my problem still how to know which CheckBox was clicked to update its state